# Python prevent data loss during file access using "with open("random.txt") as file:"

Tags: python, file, backup

I am using

```
with open("random.txt") as file:

     dump content
```

to update my JSON file. It is being executed using a QTimer every 5 seconds.
The problem occurs when I have an unexpected power-off which I cannot prevent at this time.
Sometimes the JSON file gets empty. As the documentation say when using "with open" after the execution of the  command inside the function file.close() is automatically called. My JSON file is very small (15 lines) so I does not take long for it to get updated.

How can I implement some kind of shadow copy generation of this Json file or some other backup option so I can retrieve it in case the original file gets corrupted?

Comment: I've come across this problem, (although its never been tested with an actual power-off) and I first rename the existing file to another name and then write the required file. When reading the file I read all the existing files and try to pick the most recent. (Also I put check-sums in them to validate the contents).

Comment: This is exactly I had in mind, but I thought there was maybe something wrong with my "with open" command and dumping new data. Thank you for your suggestion.